# Get date/time of commands from history on windows (cmd/ps)

Tags: windows, powershell, logging, cmd, doskey

https://www.2daygeek.com/display-date-time-linux-bash-history-command/

Found this article which seems to show equivalent how to for linux, using **HISTTIMEFORMAT** environment variable,

```
# history
    1  2017-08-16 15:30:15 yum install -y mysql-server mysql-client
    2  2017-08-16 15:30:15 service mysqld start
    3  2017-08-16 15:30:15 sysdig proc.name=sshd
```

There may be a log, or a subscription, in windows event viewer that can be enabled or registered
This feature may already exist in powershell...

Checked `doskey /?` but nothing jumps out.

❓ Is it possible to get details of **when** commands were executed, and what methods are available to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell's [`Get-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history) cmdlet (whose built-in aliases are `ghy`, `h`, and `history`) outputs [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HistoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HistoryInfo) objects, whose properties you can easily select for display with [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table), for instance:

```bash
Get-History | Format-Table Id, StartExecutionTime, CommandLine
```

Sample output:

```bash
Id StartExecutionTime    CommandLine
-- ------------------    -----------
77 4/17/2023 9:59:58 AM  Get-ChildItem *.txt
78 4/17/2023 10:00:00 AM Get-Date
```

`Get-History`'s *default* [for-display formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) shows the `Duration` property values instead of `StartExecutionTime` in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), and *neither* in *Windows PowerShell*.

Of course, you're free to include *both* `Duration` and `StartExecutionTime`.

Note:

- As of PowerShell 7.3.4, `Get-History` only ever shows the *current session*'s history, not also the *persisted* history maintained by the [`PSReadLine` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/about/about_psreadline) - see [GitHub issue #12061](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12061) for a discussion.
- Since the **solutions presented here** build on `Get-History`, they too are **effective for the *current-session* history only**, unlike `bash`'s `history` builtin.

  - Should integration with the persistent session history ever be implemented, the latter's file format would have to be extended, given that it currently stores *commands only*.

---

If you want to change the *default* formatting, you have two fundamental options:

- Author a `*.format.ps1xml` file with the desired columns and load it with [`Update-FormatData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/update-formatdata) `-PrependPath`, from your [`$PROFILE` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles).
  This is the best approach, but non-trivial, unfortunately. See below.
- *Suboptimally*, but *more simply*, create a *custom function* that wraps `Get-History`; you may also redefine the aliases to point to your custom function (e.g., `Set-Alias h Format-HistoryCustom`) -  again, place these definitions in your `$PROFILE` file:

  ```bash
  function Format-HistoryCustom {  
    Get-History @args |
      Format-Table Id, StartExecutionTime, CommandLine
  }
  ```

---

##### Adding a `StartExecutionTime` column to `Get-History`'s output, via custom formatting data loaded from `$PROFILE`:

The following implements the first approach discussed above.
Note that on *Windows PowerShell* a `Duration` column is added as well (which is present by default in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*).

The customized XML data used below was obtained by obtaining the current definitions as follows, followed by updating it by hand:

```bash
Get-FormatData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HistoryInfo |
  Export-FormatData -IncludeScriptBlock -LiteralPath HistoryInfo.format.ps1xml
```

Run this *once*, which will place a `HistoryInfo.format.ps1xml` file alongside your `$PROFILE` file and append a command to load that file with `Update-FormatData -PrependPath` to `$PROFILE` itself.

```bash
# Make sure that the directory in which $PROFILE is located exists.
$profileDir = New-Item -Type Directory -Force (Split-Path $PROFILE)

# Create a "HistoryInfo.format.ps1xml" file next to the profile file.
$customFormatFile = 'HistoryInfo.format.ps1xml'
@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Add a StartExecutionTime column to Get-History output, and on WinPS also a Duration column (included by default in PowerShell (Core)). --><Configuration><ViewDefinitions><View><Name>history</Name><ViewSelectedBy><TypeName>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HistoryInfo</TypeName></ViewSelectedBy><TableControl><TableHeaders><TableColumnHeader><Width>4</Width><Alignment>Right</Alignment></TableColumnHeader><TableColumnHeader><Width>21</Width><Alignment>Right</Alignment></TableColumnHeader><TableColumnHeader><Label>Duration</Label><Width>12</Width><Alignment>Right</Alignment></TableColumnHeader><TableColumnHeader /></TableHeaders><TableRowEntries><TableRowEntry><TableColumnItems><TableColumnItem><PropertyName>Id</PropertyName></TableColumnItem><TableColumnItem><PropertyName>StartExecutionTime</PropertyName></TableColumnItem><TableColumnItem><ScriptBlock>
                                $duration = $_.EndExecutionTime - $_.StartExecutionTime
                                if ($duration.TotalHours -ge 10) {
                                    return "{0}:{1:mm}:{1:ss}.{1:fff}" -f [int]$duration.TotalHours, $duration
                                }
                                elseif ($duration.TotalHours -ge 1) {
                                    $formatString = "h\:mm\:ss\.fff"
                                }
                                elseif ($duration.TotalMinutes -ge 1) {
                                    $formatString = "m\:ss\.fff"
                                }
                                else {
                                    $formatString = "s\.fff"
                                }

                                $duration.ToString($formatString)
</ScriptBlock></TableColumnItem><TableColumnItem><PropertyName>CommandLine</PropertyName></TableColumnItem></TableColumnItems></TableRowEntry></TableRowEntries></TableControl></View><View><Name>history</Name><ViewSelectedBy><TypeName>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.HistoryInfo</TypeName></ViewSelectedBy><WideControl><WideEntries><WideEntry><WideItem><PropertyName>CommandLine</PropertyName></WideItem></WideEntry></WideEntries></WideControl></View></ViewDefinitions></Configuration>
'@ > (Join-Path $profileDir $customFormatFile)

# Append a command to the profile that loads the formatting data into every session.
@"

# Load custom formatting data for Get-History.
Update-FormatData -PrependPath "`$PSScriptRoot/$customFormatFile"
"@ | Add-Content $PROFILE
```

Comment: I am using Powershell version 5.1.22621.963 with Windows Terminal. Next to that I also tested with version 7.3.4. The script created a Microsoft.Powershell_profile.ps1 in %userprofile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\. After closing down all terminal windows, I do see StartExecutionTime when doing Get-History, but the ConsoleHist_history file (where the entire history is persisted) still only contains the command without a timestamp. Is this correct behaviour? To me that seems to be the OP's question, right?

Comment: @VincentVerweij, as the answer notes, the solution only relates to the _non-persistent_ history (in-memory history of the current session only). As such, no files are involved. The persistent history is managed by the `PSReadLine` module, in files that record commands only, not also timestamps. The lack of integration between PowerShell's in-session-only history - as surfaced by `Get-History` - and  `PSReadLine`'s persistent history - as surfaced only via command-line editing features - is unfortunate; again, see [GitHub issue #12061](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12061)

Comment: @VincentVerweij, I've updated the answer to make the limitations clearer.